# Create H1 element in div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to a `<h1></h1>` element in a div element in HTML with jQuery. How do I do this?

```js
function show() {
  let text = "greetings"
  let divElem = document.getElementById("hello");
  divElem.innerHTML = '<h1>${text}</h1>'
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

Basically, I want to make an h1 element in the div element which displays the string contained in the text variable, "greetings" how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to ` instead of ' ?!

Also can read about it in this link : [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function show() {
  let text = "greetings"
  let divElem = document.getElementById("hello");
  divElem.innerHTML = `<h1>${text}</h1>`
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Jquery [`.html()` method.](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Also, you have to use backticks instead of quotes. (`) in order to use templating inside a "string". This is called Template literals. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
function show() {
  let text = "greetings"
  $( "#hello" ).html( `<h1>${text}</h1>` );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello"></div>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```